# Smallest prime in arithmetic progressions: upper bounds?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

This question is inspired by [@Dan Brumleve's question on finding Pratt certificates efficiently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61932/can-a-pratt-certificate-for-a-prime-be-found-in-polynomial-time). In a comment, I say that his problem is as hard as factoring, as long as the following problem is "easy" (i.e., can be solved in polynomial time):

> Given $N > 2$, find a prime $p$ such that $$p \equiv 1 \pmod{N} \tag{1}.$$

(Of course, [Dirichlet's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) assures us that infinitely many such $p$ exist.)

Now, I do not know of a clever way to find such a $p$, so I suggested simply iterating through the arithmetic progression $1+kN$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$, and terminating when we hit the first prime number. Clearly, this procedure is efficient if and only if the smallest prime $p$ satisfying $(1)$ is at most $N^{O(1)}$. (*Edit: This claim is incorrect; see below.*) I want to know if such a bound holds or not.

More generally,

> Given an integer $N$, what upper bound do we know on the smallest prime satisfying $(1)$?

I did a quick check on Wikipedia and Mathworld, but cannot find any relevant results.

*Edit:* Turns out the claim in the question is false. The procedure will be efficient only if the smallest prime is $O(N \cdot\mathrm{poly}\log N)$, which seems very unlikely. In any case, I will just keep this question as it is, since it makes sense as a stand-alone question as well.

Comment: I apologize for the mistake (which is only tangentially related to this question anyway), and also not researching the topic properly. I overlooked the link to Linnik's theorem at the bottom of the wiki page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The relevant results are found under the heading, Linnik's Theorem. Linnik proved that the least prime congruent to $a$ mod $d$ is at most $cd^L$ for some absolute constants $c$ and $L$. The current best bound is $L\le5.2$. On the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis, you can show there's a prime less than $(\phi(d)\log d)^2$, where that's Euler's phi-function. It is conjectured there's always a prime less than $d^2$.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my searching was quite sloppy then :).

Comment: Since a second answer has been posted, I unaccepted your answer for now. I hope you don't mind :). I will accept some answer after a few days...

Comment: @Srivatsan Narayanan: I support Gerry's answer.  Mine is just a silly offhand remark; his points to a major theorem.  :)

Comment: Is the constant $c$ known as well ?

Comment: @Peter, I don't know. I suppose one could chase through the literature on Linnik's Theorem to see. But since 5.2 is conjectured to be far from best possible for $L$, there may not be so much interest in pinning down a value for $c$.

Comment: Having an explicit value of $c$ might be useful even if $L$ is not optimal. Without an explicit value of $c$ proofs of along the lines: "For $d$ larger then $d_0$ this follows from Linnik's theorem, for $d \leq d_0$ this follows from inspection" are not possible because $d_0$ cannot be made explicit.

Answer (score 7):

Gerry Myerson has answered your main question, so I'll address the other part.  I don't think that the claim is false, though certainly it's not proven.  In any case I wouldn't say it's "very unlikely".

In fact it seems quite likely to me that the smallest k with $kn+1$ prime will be $O((\log n)^3)$ -- indeed, probably even $O((\log n)^2(\log\log n)^e)$ for some e.

Disregarding $n<20$, $e=0.18$ works up to 30 million with a constant of 1.  A braver mathematician might conjecture that it holds for $e=0$ and a somewhat larger constant.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Thanks! Is there any conditional result or any explicit conjecture of this vein?

Comment: @Srivatsan Narayanan: I do not know of a conditional proof.  I'm sure there's a conjecture on the subject--older than mine, that is--but I haven't found it in a cursory search.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Charles' conjecture is similar to Cramér's conjecture, generalized to arithmetic progressions, but concerning only the first gap; the same heuristic arguments apply.  One thing I don't understand is why the log(log(n))^e term?

Comment: @Dan Brumleve: I'm quite confident that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there are only finitely many prime gaps larger than $(\log x)^{2+\varepsilon}$ but Maier's (1985?) paper shook my confidence in the Cramer model enough that I question not just $(\log x)^2$ but even $C(\log x)^2.$  (I wouldn't bet money that it fails for $C=2$, but it wouldn't shock me.)  This problem is similar: I'm not confident enough on a theoretical or computational basis to say $(\log n)^2$.  But in this case I opted for the slightly stronger form $(\log n)^2(\log\log n)^e$ rather than just $(\log n)^{2+\varepsilon}$.

Comment: My apologies, it looks like the font makes it quite hard to distinguish between the $\varepsilon$ (epsilon) and the $e$ (e) in exponents.  The only exponent with $e$ is the penultimate, $(\log\log n)^e.$

Comment: Would this give a similar upper bound for the quantity $r_{0}(n)$ defined as the least non negative integer $r$ such that both $n-r$ and $n+r$ are prime?